# How to pass Form data to jquery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a form with three fields course code/month/year when submitted fetches student data and displays in a data table. All i want is to display the selected month and year with course code in the exported pdf as sub message under the heading. How can I Do that

This is my data table code

```
$('#example1').DataTable();
        var Table = $('#example2').DataTable({
          "paging": true,
          "lengthChange": true,
          "searching": true,
          "ordering": true,
          "info": true,
          "autoWidth": false,
          "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 30, -1], [10, 20, 30, "All"]],
        

          dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
          {orientation: 'landscape',
          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          messageTop: 'Month  ****                          Year',
          pageSize: 'A4',
          footer: true,

          exportOptions:{
            columns:[0,1,2,3,4,5,7]
            rows: function(idx, data, node) {
            if ( data[7] > "0") {
              return true;
            }
          }
        },
          title: function () { return "Nipunatha Sisu Saviya Stipend Program" }
      }
```

My form to submit is

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="{{ url('/home/retrieveData') }}" id="sample_form">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                  <label>Select Course Code</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <select name="course_code" id="course_code" class="form-control select20" data-live-search="true" style="width: 100%;">
                  @foreach($course['course'] as $value)
                    <option>{{ $value->CourseCode }}</option>

                  @endforeach 
                  </select>
                </div>
                <!-- <div>
                  <select class="mdb-select md-form" searchable="Search here..">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
                    <option value="1">USA</option>
                    <option value="2">Germany</option>
                    <option value="3">France</option>
                    <option value="3">Poland</option>
                    <option value="3">Japan</option>
                  </select>
                </div> -->
                  
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                  <label>Select Month</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <select name="month" id="month" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option> 
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                  <label>Select Year</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                    <option value="2022">2022</option>
                     
                  </select>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <select name="course_code" id="course_code" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option>College of technology</option>
                    <option>Technical Colleges</option>

                  </select>
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group" align="center">
                  <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-info btn-flat" value="Search" />
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: You have two problems: Submit the form and display data into `datatables` and display a string on the pdf file header when exporting the file.

Comment: I do display the data in data table.. but how can i use this variable in Sub heading in pdf export?

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).